# Why do villagers think my healing spell is a fire spell?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'll be walking around the towns and cities of Skyrim, when all of a sudden, I'm told my guards and passerby that I should take care with those flames. Except I don't actually have any fire casting spells equipped when this happens; all I have is healing. Is this a scripted dialogue that NPCs will say no matter what spell you have?

Comment: If you have a fire enchanted weapon in your hand that could trigger the same response. See http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Fire_Damage#Notes

Comment: what is your destruction magic level?

Comment: @Dragonrage 26.

Comment: how about you restoration?

Comment: @Dragonrage 33.

Comment: Is it possible that you might just be accidentally mistaking your fire spell for a healing spell? Very common and easy mistake to make... Happens to me all the time. I burned Whiterun to the ground 3 times by mistake. Whoops!

Comment: @Ben definitely not.

Comment: I hate to say this, but it turns out that I'm completely wrong. The quest that makes NPCs complain about fire checks for the MagicDamageFire keyword on the magic effect. The check was in a different location from the checks for the other two dialog types. As for why they complain about your healing spell, I have no idea. I must have been remembering wrong earlier when I said that NPCs complained about flames to me... I just talked to dozens of people and none of them complained about fire. The closest they got was asking me to douse that "magic", and "douse" is reminiscent of fire.

Comment: @armadillo Are any of the healing spells mistagged with MagicDamageFire?

Comment: @WillihamTotland Doesn't look like it.

Comment: @fi12 Do you have any effects that boost your destruction level? Also, do you remember the specific wording of the comment, and who said it?

Comment: @armadillo I don't think so. Guards and townspeople will say "take care with those flames" or "make sure you don't burn the place down". If it helps, I also equip an orcish sword of scorching, although the enchantment ran out so now it just functions as a regular sword..

Comment: Do you mean that you're wielding a healing spell in one hand, and the sword of scorching in the other, or you just have the sword in your inventory? Is the sword drawn when people make the comments?

Comment: @armadillo I have the sword drawn in my right hand with healing in the left when people make the comments.

Comment: That explains it. A sword with a fire enchantment can provoke comments about flames, even when it's out of charges. I checked this in the game and in the Creation Kit just now. @Paul looks like you had the answer all along. The healing spell doesn't make any difference for the flames comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @Paul and @Armadillo, this was due to me dual wielding an Orcish Sword of Scorching in my right hand while casting a healing spell in my left. It wasn't the healing spell that triggered this response, rather, it was the sword (even though it ran out of the enchantment, it still triggers this same sort of response). See [here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Fire_Damage#Notes) for more information.

Answer (score -8):

I don't think so with a spell fire occurs, even tough it occurs for that your spell won't be a reason for it.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean - would you mind clarifying?

Comment: @twobugs I _think_ he meant that the healing spell is not the reason why the villagers are saying that; there must have been another accident

Comment: That's possible, but the other answer offers a pretty good explanation for this phenomenon. This seems more like a comment

Comment: @twobugs The answer sentence makes no sense to me. We are guessing what user150436 meant, so I think this is a good indication that a clarification is necessary.